# Minimum length of employment

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

Is there any minimum length of employment for a UK visitor visa application? Would it be risky to apply for the visa just after getting a job even if I have a satisfactory bank account?

Comment: If you were unemployed before the recent start of your new employment, the visa officer may wonder about the source of the money in your "satisfactory bank account."

Comment: I was employed untill the end of February for 3 years, will be employed around June and need to go the UK in July.

Comment: "What type of job do you have that after a month working you can just pick up and come to the UK?" will be what the Immigration Officer/visa official/other border agent will ask you.  Also, "Why did you leave your job in February?"  They will see a new job as trying to throw them off, and they will consider you a potential overstayer.

Comment: I am a dentist. I finished my postgraduate program at dental school and assumed the titled of 'specialist dentist' so i need to look for another job.

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum length of employment (nor for that matter, that an individual be employed). Applicants are asked to demonstrate eligibility in the visa category requested and to provide  a lot of background information: employment history, educational background, financial viability, family, connections to home country, etc.. Along with your premise for entering the UK, the ECO would use everything you present to come to a decision whether intentions are genuine and a visa issued.